# jquery compare data in same row, if correct show content of third data in row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to compare the first `td` with the `input` of the second `td` and when they are the same the third `td` has to say that the comparison is correct. It needs to be dynamic so it works for each table row.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1234567890123</td> <!-- EAN Number -->
        <td><input type="text"></td> <!-- Barcode scanner gives input -->
        <td><span>Correct!</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2345678901234</td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><span>Correct!</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
td > span {
    display:none;
}
```

jQuery (can't figure out what to do):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").keyup(function(){
        if($('td:first-of-type').text === $('td:nth-of-type(2)').val()){
            $('span').css('cssText','display:block;');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to base it off of where the `input` is in the DOM. Currently you are selecting the first and second `td` in the entire page every time. Also you want the value of the `input` in the second `td`, not the `td` but since you are using `keyup` the context of the function, `this`, is that `input` already. Also you aren't using the `css` function correctly.

Example:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("input").keyup( function() {
        // Cache current input user was typing in as jQuery object
        var $input = $(this);

        // Find first td in tr of the input user was typing
        var $firstTd = $input.parent().prev();

        // Find last td in tr of the input user was typing
        var $lastTd = $input.parent().next();

        // Compare text value of first td with value user typed in input
        if ($firstTd.text() === $input.val()) {
            // If equal find span in last td and set display block
            $lastTd.find('span').css('display', 'block');
        }
        else {
            // If not equal find span in last td and set display none
            $lastTd.find('span').css('display', 'none');
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d5ab79vc/1/

Comment: Looks like it should work, but i don't get the span to be displayed

Comment: @user269811 Sorry updated answer. Had copied your code and was missing some closing parentheses. Also added a fiddle showing it working.

Comment: But when change the correct one correct writing doesn't get hidden again should add one more if if ($firstTd.text() !== $input.val()) {
            // If equal find span in last td and set display block
            $lastTd.find('span').css('display', 'none');
        }

Comment: updated to handle hiding when value changes and it is showing

Answer (score 0):

You're really close. Your logic is correct. Try using IDs for selectors instead of nth-of-type. Unless you need this to be as dynamic as you're demonstrating.

Ex.

```
if($('#R1C1').text === $('#R1C2)').val()){
        $('#R1C3 span').css('cssText','display:block;');
    }
```

R1C1 = row 1, cell 1, etc.

Comment: Yes it needs to be dynamic

Answer (score 0):

```
<table class="casa">
    <tr>
        <td id="one">1234567890123</td> <!-- EAN Number -->
        <td><input type="text" id="first"></td> <!-- Barcode scanner gives input -->
        <td><span id="x">Correct!</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="two">2345678901234</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="second"></td>
        <td><span id="y">Correct!</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

js

```
 $(".casa").keyup(function(){
        if($("#first").val() === $("#one").text()){

            $("#x").css({"display":"block"})
        }
         if($("#second").val() === $("#two").text()){

            $("#y").css({"display":"block"})
        }
    }
    );
```

css

```
td > span {
    display:none;

}
```

Comment: Needs to be dynamic, so can't use id's